# Find highest index with value non zero in dafny

Tags: verification, dafny

In Dafny I want to find the highest index in an int array where the value is != 0
The method requires that such a value exists
I tried this but can't figure out how it can't provy any of the ensures clauses.
Especially for the clause

```
ensures 0 <= result
```

It seems weird, as result can't be assigned when the loop entering conditiong is not fulfilled which is excatly 0 <= i
I only could think of more invariants but not any that help.

```
method HighestNonZeroIndex(arr: array<int>) returns (result: int)
    requires arr.Length >= 1
    requires exists i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length && arr[i] != 0
    ensures 0 <= result 
    ensures result < arr.Length && arr[result] != 0
{
    var i := arr.Length - 1;

    while i >= 0
    invariant -1 <= i < arr.Length
    decreases i
    {
        if arr[i] != 0 {
            result := i;
            return;
    }
    i := i - 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Dafny doesn't realize that because of the `requires` clause, it is impossible for the while loop to finish normally -- ie, the only way the loop exits is via the return statement.

You need to add more invariants to prove that it is impossible for the loop to exit normally.

I would start with an invariant that says "there exists an index that we haven't visited yet such that the array has a nonzero value in that index".

Comment: I tried 
invariant exists j :: 0 <= j < i && arr[j] != 0
but it can't be proven on entry or to be maintained by the loop. Do you have Any idea?

Comment: Should it be `<= i`?

Comment: You can write this program very elegantly with a `for i := arr.Length downto 0` loop in Dafny. With a full specification (see my comments in response to the entry below), you only need to declare one loop invariant.

Answer (score 0):

I added an invariant as described by James, which helped generally but didnt make the method verifiable.
I had to take a different approach in making the method theoretically return -1 if there is no not null value. Because of this I had to remove the problematic postcondition clauses anyway.
Now this postcondition seems to do the trick:

```
ensures forall i| 0 <= result < i < arr.Length :: arr[i] == 0
```

Here is the full method.

```
method HighestNonZeroIndex(arr: array<int>) returns (result: int)
requires arr.Length > 0
requires exists i :: 0 <= i < arr.Length && arr[i] != 0
ensures 0 <= result < arr.Length ==> arr[result] != 0
ensures forall i| 0 <= result < i < arr.Length :: arr[i] == 0
// the latter ensures clause is not needed
ensures forall i| 0 <= i < arr.Length :: result != -1 ==> arr[i] != 0 
{
   result := -1;
   var i := arr.Length - 1;

   while (i >= 0 && arr[i] == 0)
   invariant (0 <= i < arr.Length -1 )  ==> arr[i+1] == 0
   invariant result == -1 ==> forall x :: 0 <= i < x < arr.Length ==> arr[x] == 0
   invariant exists j :: 0 <= j <= i && arr[j] != 0
   invariant result != -1 ==> arr[result] != 0
   decreases i
   {
       if(arr[i] != 0)
       {
           result := i;
           return;    
       }
       i := i - 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: This method specification allows the implementation to just return `-1`, without even looking at the array. One problem is that the first `ensures` clause says that _if_ the result is an index, then it is the index of a non-zero element. You want `&&` instead of `==>`. Another problem is the third `ensures` clause, which says that either `result` is `-1` or all array elements are non-zero. Two other simplifications you can make to the specification are to drop the first `requires` clause (since it follows from the second, and to drop `0 <=` in the second `ensures` clause.